# Change state of a promise in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a service like below; with `.cancel()` method to resolve the promise in order to cancel it. The problem is once i call `.cancel()`, the promise is resolved and then all consequence calls will fail.

Is there anyway i can fix this? Changing from `resolved` back to `pending`?

```
.service('MyService', function($http, $q) {

  this.canceller = $q.defer()
  this.my_func = function(params) {
    params.timeout = canceller.promise
    return $http.get(url, params)
  }

  this.cancel = function () {
    this.canceller.resolve('Cancel my_func ...');
  }
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to change the state of the promise. You should fix the design so that each HTTP request uses its own promise. Currently, all the HTTP requests made by my_func share the same promise. The promise should come from the caller. Or it should be created by the service at each request and returned with the http promise.

Comment: @JBNizet i thought of it as well but haven't found a way. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Just do as $http does: take a canceller promise as argument of your my_func() function.

Comment: @JBNizet is there anyway to call it from one controller and cancel it from another?